# Can there be some non-electromagnetic radiation which would be perceived by human eye as light?

Tags: biophysics, biology

Can there be some non-electromagnetic radiation which would be perceived by human eye as light? I mean, say ultra-sound or some particle rays etc.

Comment: Perhaps not exactly in the spirit of your question but if you press on your eye to deform it, you can cause all sorts of visual phenomena.  I'd call that triggering nerves via the coulomb force and the pauli exclusion principle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like neutrons can cause visual perception: Visual phenomena noted by human subjects on exposure to neutrons of energies less than 25 million electron volts, Science. 1971 May 21;172(3985):868-70, "Six subjects reported multiple starlike flashes and short streaks on exposure to neutrons of energies up to 25 million electron volts. The probable mechanism is interaction with the retinal rods by proton recoils and by alpha particles released from neutron reactions with carbon and oxygen. These observations are similar to light flashes and streaks seen by astronauts who are exposed to high-energy cosmic rays on translunar flight."